# como remover una palabra de un string C#

Tags: c#

Tengo esta problematica, necesito remover este `string` de una cadena pero no ubico como solucionarlo ya que tiene "" entre las palabras:

xmlns:cartaporte="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3"

este es mi codigo:

```
var string = "xmlns:cartaporte="+"http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3";
```

como concateno lo "" en el string para remover la palabra :

```
string newString = xy.Replace(x, string.Empty);
```

Comment: No sé termina de entender que querés remover.

Comment: tenes que mejorar la redaccion de la pregunta. Por un lado concatenas y por el otro removes. y no entendemos que parte de tu cadena queres remover.

Comment: Hola david, podrias decir si las respuestas dadas te fueron utiles y en caso de serlo marcar como aceptada la que mas te haya ayudado, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Un ejemplo rápido para remover es:

```
string word = "hola";
word = word.Replace("l", "")
```

Ahora, si tu problema es que contiene un carácter especial puedes hacer:

```
string word = @"/hola/";
if(word.Contains("/"))
{
  word = word.Replace(@"/", ""); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer lo que quieres debes usar la **barra invertida (\)** antes de las **dobles comillas**, de esta forma el compilador entiende que tu **string** contiene el caracter de **doble comilla (")**.

```
string palabra = "xmlns:cartaporte=\"http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3\"";
string nuevaPalabra = palabra.Replace(palabra, otraPalabra);
```

Aquí usas la **función** **Replace** para reemplazar de la **variable palabra** cualquier subcadena que desees.

La **barra invertida** va antes de las **dobles comillas internas**, ya que como es un **string** tienes que encerrarlo de todas formas con **dobles comillas externas**, y las **comillas externas no van con la barra invertida**.